# simple_html_dom -

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I have used CURL to grab this URL

```
$url = "http://www.juno.co.uk/all/today/?items_per_page=100&show_digital=0&show_tracks=0&show_covers=0";

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL,"$url");
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20); //give it adequate time
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

if(!$complete = curl_exec($c))
    {
        echo "Failed to curl $url\n";
    }
```

I am then trying pass into simple html dom using

```
$home_page = str_get_html($complete);
```

this is throwing a 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object' error

```
foreach($home_page->find('tr.row2') as $home_details)
{
      //do stuff
    }
```

When I change the 'items_per_page' parameter to 50 then it works. The link above is valid and when I echo $complete it is displaying the page code.

simple_html_dom is loaded earlier in the script and works correctly.

I have tried file_get_html instead of CURL and same result

Comment: And when you var_dump `$home_page`, what do you get?

Comment: This may mean that `str_get_html` returns an Exception, try to `var_dump` it. Your HTML may not be valid for instance.

Comment: You could also try to use `file_get_html` directly with the url (without using `curl`) since I guess making a `GET` request instead of a `POST` should give you the same result